# Right way to inflate android.support.v4.app.fragment from xml

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

Please, help.

Which is right?

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <android.support.v4.app.fragment
        android:id="@+id/advertListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.myapp.fragment.AdvertListFragment"/>
```

Or like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/advertListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.myapp.fragment.AdvertListFragment"/>
```

Without prefix  "android.support.v4".

P.s. I haven't more details

Comment: If you want to inflate this `android.support.v4.app.fragment` (to support older devices) it's correct **with**

Comment: the first one should be the correct way to go

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
<fragment
    ...
```

inflated in an activity that `extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

For further details, it's [`FragmentActivity.onCreateView()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#241) that handles the inflation for `fragment` elements.